# How do I get a JQuery object inside a template literal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, template-literals

So often I have a JQuery object such as

```
var element = $('<h1>Title</h1>');
```

I will make some operations on it, and later, I want to embed it inside of a template literal, so it displays as if it were using the $().append from jquery. Here is my attempt

```
var secondElement = $(`<div><div>${element}</div></div>`);
$('#someRandomDiv').append(secondElement);
```

This, as expected, outputs

```
<div><div>[Object object]</div></div>
```

as it is referencing an object, not actually the HTML of the element. However I want it to be .

```
<div><div><h1>Title</h1></div</div>
```

Is there a way of doing this? Optimally it would still use the template literals, and of course, it is best if it uses native js/jquery functionality, rather than workarounds.

Comment: element is not a string so it is not going to work in a template literal. You would be better off appending it to the right location than doing something that would convert it to a string.

Comment: @Taplar By proper I meant that,  like you said there are many ways to do it,  but, I am looking for something that is most natively built into js/jquery, not just some work around.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Edited it to reflect that.

Comment: Let try my answer given in below, that may be work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the underlying HTMLElement object by accessing `element[0]`, then what you want is the html string, which you can get with `.outerHTML`. So:

```js
var element = $('<h1>Title</h1>');

var secondElement = $(`<div><div>${element[0].outerHTML}</div></div>`);

console.log(secondElement[0].outerHTML)
// Logs: <div><div><h1>Title</h1></div></div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery methods instead

```js
var element = $('<h1>Title</h1>');
   
var secondElement = $(`<div>`).append(element).wrap(`<div>`).parent();
   

console.log(secondElement[0].outerHTML)
// Logs: <div><div><h1>Title</h1></div></div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -4):

Try following code:

```
var element = $('<h1>Title</h1>');
var secondElement = $(`<div><div>${element.prop('outerHTML')}</div></div>`);
$('#someRandomDiv').append(secondElement);
```

Comment: "You should avoid wrap as jQuery object when declaring element. Try following code: <shows wrapping the element up with jQuery>" what?